# LCS algorithm in dot plot

Tags: python-2.7

I hope somebody can help me out, I just can't get my program to run. I am trying to create a full LCS (longest common substring) matrix (and later to find the longest common substring) in python. I can't get the dot plot together. I am trying to append it to my empty matrix but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
def compute_lcs(seq_A, seq_B):
  longest = 0 
  DotPlot = []
  m = len(seq_A)
  n = len(seq_B)
  for row in range(1,m+1): #set up DotPlot
    for col in range(1, n+1):
        temp_row = []
        if seq_A[row] == seq_B[col]:
            if row == 0 or col == 0:
                DotPlot[row, col] = 1
                temp_row.append(DotPlot[row,col])   
            else:                       
                DotPlot[row, col] = DotPlot[row-1, col-1] + 1
                temp_row.append(DotPlot[row, col])
        else: 
            DotPlot[row, col] = 0
            temp_row.append(DotPlot[row, col])  
  return DotPlot
```

Thank you!

Comment: Local variables (`DotPlot`) should be `dot_plot`.

Comment: State what doesn't work. What errors are you getting. Off hand, you are trying to index as `DotPlot[row, col]` when it is a list. This will give an error. Consider using Numpy arrays.